# Monodevelop compile issue with ReadAsync

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

Monodevelop V5.1 & V5.9.8
Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.1

Monodevelop is complaing over this:

```
while ((numBytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, 1024)) >0)
```

Yet intellisense offers it up as an option

> Error CS1061: Type `System.IO.Stream' does not contain a definition
>   for`ReadAsync' and no extension method `ReadAsync' of type`
>   System.IO.Stream' could be found. Are you missing an assembly
>   reference? (CS1061)

Comment: It looks like it has got something to do with the fact that's it's an add-in project.  I cant target a framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually adding the framework fixed it

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```